# React Native - exporting an object based on switch case loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to React Native and I'm struggling with an object exporting problem. In my app, I'm receiving from back-end simple string that I store in a variable `Settings.translationType`. When it's received, I'm rendering a simple view, let's say like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Translations from '../constants/Translations';

export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>{Translations.one}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

And there comes to some troubles. I'm having a .js file (Translations), that depends on what comes from back-end service, it gives proper translated category names. It looks like this:

```
import Category1 from './translations/Category1';
import Category2 from './translations/Category2';
import Category3 from './translations/Category3';

const Translations = () => {
    switch (Settings.translationType) {
        case '2': 
            return Category2;
        case '3': 
            return Category3;
        default:
            return Category1;
    }
}

export default Translations();
```

Inside the `./translations` folder, I'm having three .js files like below:

```
import LocalizedStrings from 'localized-strings';

const Category1 = new LocalizedStrings({
    en: {
        one: 'Restaurant',
        two: 'Café',
        three: 'Pub'
    },
    fi: {
        one: 'Ravintola',
        two: 'Kahvila',
        three: 'Pub'
    },
    sw: {
        one: 'Restaurang',
        two: 'Kafé',
        three: 'Pub'
    },
    de: {
        one: 'Restaurant',
        two: 'Cafe',
        three: 'Pub'
    },
})

export default Category1;
```

After I run my app in Expo CLI, the `Settings.translationType` is always fetched correctly from BE, but I'm having an error like: `Unable to resolve module './translations/Category1.js' from '~/RN/MyProject/src/constants/Translations.js': The module './translations/Category1.js' could not be found from '~RN/MyProject/src/constants/Translations.js'. Indeed, non of these files exists: (and there are listed the files with other extensions of Category1 file, located at ~/RN/MyProject/src/constants/translations/)`

I think I'm having some logical problem (syntax looks ok) so if I'm missing something or there is any other solution, thank you in advice!

EDIT:
Added my folder structure.

[image: Folder structure]

Comment: Where is your translations folder located? Can you tell it's path?

Comment: `Translations.js` is located at `~/RN/MyProject/src/constants/` folder, where there is also a `translations` folder, so all looks ok...

Comment: Can you share your folder structure?

Comment: Added it in my question

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think I found your problem. In Translations.js your export statement should be

`export default Translations;`

instead of

`export default Translations();`

Also make sure all your Category files are exported the same way.
See if this works.

Comment: All Category files are exported the same way, checked twice. Also I have already tried both export version you have given there and both throws the same error

Comment: Okay.. Can you also share your folder structure?

Comment: Added it in my question

Comment: Sorry, everything seems right in place and I can't figure out the problem. Also tried it on snack and there was no problem. Try restarting the Expo CLI.

Answer (score 0):

I found that in my source file I have misspelled the file's path, syntax bugs are the worst. After that change, all works correct. And just for your knowledge [Atin Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10574385/atin-singh), `export default Translations` without braces passes `''` instead of the proper translation string. Thanks all for your help!

Comment: Glad it worked out. And thanks for mentioning that. Cheers :)